# WordPress ACF Repeaters with Timber/Twig

Tags: wordpress, twig, advanced-custom-fields, timber

Looked around the Google a lot but couldn't find the solution. I'm new to Twig/Timber but I have a lot Laravel experience so it's similar but I'm not familiar with how to work with ACF Repeater fields within Twig templating.

I've got my ACF Repeater Field Setup:

Repeater Name: Contact

Within the Repeater I have:

```
Contact Name: contact_name

Contact E-mail Address: contact_email_address

Contact Phone Number: contact_phone_number
```

This is what's currently "not working" in my Twig file:

```
{% if post.contact %}
  <h3>Contacts</h3>
  {% for contact in post.contact %}
    <p><strong>Name:</strong> {{ post.contact_name }}</p>
    <p><strong>E-mail:</strong> {{ post.contact_email_address }}</p>
    <p><strong>Phone:</strong> {{ post.contact_phone_number }}</p>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

But no dice. I know `post.contact` is working because it's displaying `<h3>Contacts</h3>`. I'm more concerened about the foreach that doesn't seem to be working as intended.

Thanks for any help or guidance.

Update: I looked at the documentation and tried:

```
{% for contact in post.contact('contact') %}
```

But that didn't seem to have any effect either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolved with:

```
{% if post.contact %}
  <h3>Contacts</h3>
  {% for contact in post.meta('contacts') %}
    <p><strong>Name:</strong> {{ contact.contact_name }}</p>
    <p><strong>E-mail:</strong> {{ contact.contact_email_address }}</p>
    <p><strong>Phone:</strong> {{ contact.contact_phone_number }}</p>
  {% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This should work without the post.meta line if you loop like you did in your opening post: {% for contact in post.contacts %} in some cases I needed to use: {% for item in post.get_field(’repeatet_fieldname’) %}